# Android Webcore: libwebcore.so crashes on API 15 & 16

Tags: android, webkit, android-webview

My app uses Android Webview to display some user interfaces, we found a crash which is reported by users, the stack trace is like this:

```
#00 pc 00110c74 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#01 pc 00110cb8 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#02 pc 00110e26 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#03 pc 0011118c /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#04 pc 0012c4c6 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#05 pc 0039c8ac /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#06 pc 003a05d2 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#07 pc 00394bce /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#08 pc 00394cac /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#09 pc 00394d44 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#10 pc 0015d8b8 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#11 pc 00160f24 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#12 pc 0016e3a2 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#13 pc 0016ce36 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#14 pc 0028b484 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#15 pc 00289952 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#16 pc 0028a55c /system/lib/libwebcore.so
#17 pc 00110208 /system/lib/libwebcore.so
java:
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:591)
android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue(Native Method)
android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:113)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:1057)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

by using our trace report system , I found that this crash only occurs on devices with API 15 or API 16 system(API under 15 is not traced), I can't find a way to reproduce this crash.

Is there anyone who has some experience for this?

Comment: That runnable is used for a lot of things, so by itself it crashing isn't super informative. Any idea what the view is doing when the crash happens?

Comment: @Turnsole the crash comes in rather random scenarios, but it seems to appear a little more frequently when there comes animation on web pages.

Comment: this problem seems has something to do with my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831964/signal-11-sigsegv-crash-in-galaxy-s3-android-webview