# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 27830 (ple.myfragexample) -- only on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-fragments, out-of-memory, android-4.2-jelly-bean, universal-image-loader

I am using FragmentActivity in my application with several Fragments. Each of these fragments hold an image and some text with animation. When user swipes on the screen, the fragment changes.

Now I have been working on this since 10 days and have tested the FragmentActivity on different devices with different Android versions. The reason that I am stuck on this from last 10 days is I am getting a crash

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 27830 (ple.myfragexample)
```

Now, this error occurs only when I test the FragmentActivity on Android 4.1.2 particularly. It would run fine on Android 2.3.3, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.2 and even 2.2. The error log is as below:

```
08-07 14:34:13.843: D/dalvikvm(27830): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3845K, 14% free 35407K/40903K, paused 4ms, total 14ms
08-07 14:34:13.848: I/dalvikvm-heap(27830): Grow heap (frag case) to 39.590MB for 3932176-byte allocation
08-07 14:34:13.878: D/dalvikvm(27830): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 5% free 39244K/40903K, paused 11ms+4ms, total 30ms
08-07 14:34:13.928: D/dalvikvm(27830): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 39244K/40903K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
08-07 14:34:13.928: I/dalvikvm-heap(27830): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 8847376-byte allocation
08-07 14:34:13.953: D/dalvikvm(27830): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 5% free 39235K/40903K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
08-07 14:34:13.953: E/dalvikvm-heap(27830): Out of memory on a 8847376-byte allocation.
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ea8508 self=0x41e989c8
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   | sysTid=27830 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074937648
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   | schedstat=( 2591504030 1697770606 13588 ) utm=221 stm=38 core=0
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:625)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:478)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3449)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at com.example.myfragexample.pages.Page6.onCreateView(Page6.java:52)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429) 
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
08-07 14:34:13.953: I/dalvikvm(27830):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 14:34:13.953: A/libc(27830): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 27830 (ple.myfragexample)
```

I have searched a lot over the internet and tried many thing about this, however, the working of my Fragments got smoother on devices with any other version of Android, but just on Android 4.1.2. I also tried to use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), but it still crashes with Fatal signal 11. The error log I get when I am using Universal Image Loader is as below:

```
08-07 14:20:03.678: D/dalvikvm(27268): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3857K, 32% free 33002K/48455K, paused 31ms, total 34ms
08-07 14:20:03.678: I/dalvikvm-heap(27268): Grow heap (frag case) to 37.241MB for 3932176-byte allocation
08-07 14:20:03.708: D/dalvikvm(27268): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 24% free 36837K/48455K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
08-07 14:20:03.738: D/dalvikvm(27268): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 24% free 36837K/48455K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 30ms
08-07 14:20:03.848: D/dalvikvm(27268): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 24% free 36837K/48455K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
08-07 14:20:03.848: I/dalvikvm-heap(27268): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 8847376-byte allocation
08-07 14:20:03.883: D/dalvikvm(27268): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 24% free 36828K/48455K, paused 32ms, total 35ms
08-07 14:20:03.883: E/dalvikvm-heap(27268): Out of memory on a 8847376-byte allocation.
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268): "pool-1-thread-1" prio=4 tid=12 RUNNABLE
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4293af60 self=0x4f6c9470
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   | sysTid=27283 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1098606736
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   | schedstat=( 2735922613 2106917058 1146 ) utm=266 stm=7 core=0
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:625)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:478)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:672)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromDrawable(BaseImageDownloader.java:184)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:84)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:82)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:68)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:284)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:243)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:125)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-07 14:20:03.888: I/dalvikvm(27268):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-07 14:20:03.888: A/libc(27268): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 27283 (pool-1-thread-1)
```

Now, I know there are lots of questions with Fatal signal 11 on here too, but I am concerned and confused as I am getting this crash **only on Android 4.1.2** and not on any other Android versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue is solved now. I just got my images re-sized from my Graphics team. Previously I was using 1280x768 resolution images but I got them scaled down to 800x480 and the crash is gone. Thanks for all the suggestions though.

Also, I think Jelly Bean (4.x) has enhanced UI and so, it occupies more memory for handling the UI itself than the lower versions of Android, and that's why it was not able to manage handling(scaling down) the larger images.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my question:

[Strange crash drawing on canvas on Android 4.0.3. A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989120/very-strange-crash-drawing-on-canvas-on-android-4-0-3-a-libc-fatal-signal-11)

maybe it's the same problem. The issue arises when I try to use a small number for stroke or others `Paint` properties.

```
setStrokeWidth(0.007f);
```

Never solved, I suggest to scale the Canvas and use bigger numbers.

Comment: Yes, it really is strange but still I would like to get some more suggestions. I have previously used UIL and it is one of the best library to handle images, and I am not able to understand why would it crash with that too. The quality of the image is also of great concern in my App. Apart from all this, when I test my app, it is running fine on devices even with low memory or low specs having any other Android version than 4.1.2.

Comment: Can you give the library link?

Comment: I suggesto you to refine your question and specify that you're using a specific library **with a link**.

Comment: Okay, I will edit my Question with the link, however, I actually do not want to use this library. I just tried to check if there was some problem in my code and if UIL was able to manage this problem. I only want to use Fragments with FragmentActivity, as I need to manage animation for each Fragment and also need to handle MediaPlayer for each Fragment.